# Generic type return does not accept object containing the same defined fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a function which takes a generic tree like object consisting of node like `children` which in turn can **optionaly** have their own `children`, the second argument is a function `predicate` with the currently visited node to pass it to the filter function.

I don't care much about the extra properties inside the `tree` (except for `children`) and `node` like objects. For this reason I chose to implement this function using generics. Below is a simplified version of my code.

```js
interface NodeLike {
    children?: NodeLike[];
}

interface TreeLike {
    children: NodeLike[];
}

export function filterChildrenFromTree<T extends TreeLike, N extends NodeLike>(
    t: T,
    predicate: (n: N) => boolean
): T {
    const newTree = {
        children: t.children.filter(predicate)
    };

    return newTree;
}
```

Unfortunately typescript gives me the following error under the `return` line:

```
Type '{ children: NodeLike[]; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

If state that `T` in this case extends a TreeLike object, why does typescript complains when I do return an object in the expected format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T extends TreeLike, but TreeLike doesn't extend T. The code tries to return TreeLike instead of T.

Type of newTree should be T, but it's '{ children: NodeLike[]; }'.

The most simple fix

```js
const newTree = {
    ...t, 
    children: t.children.filter(predicate)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you want, but for me, a more generic approach might be to describe your tree abstraction in functional terms, rather than as a known `children` property on each node. You could define the following function types, representing the optional nature of children with the type `T[]|undefined`but here I've chosen an empty array to represent the same situation as it simplifies the logic:

```
type ChildSelector<T> = (item: T) => T[];
type Pred<T> = (item: T, index: number) => boolean;
type TreeAssembler<T> = (children: T[]) => T;
```

This now allows you to write a filtering function that has no constraints on the type of tree that can be filtered

```
export function filterChildrenFromTree<T>(
  t: T,
  childSelector: ChildSelector<T>,
  predicate: Pred<T>,
  treeAssembler: TreeAssembler<T>
): T {
  const children = childSelector(t);
  const newTree = treeAssembler(children.filter(predicate));
  return newTree;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting up such solution, but I was more interested in understanding the nature of the error

Comment: @Rigotti No worries. Just giving you another perspective on decoupling various aspects of dealing with tree-like structures.